# Will an app be placed into background when I press Home key?

Tags: android

I know there are three keys Back, Home and Overview in Android 8.1.

After I open an app, the app will be placed into background if I press Home key? and will the app be released by system control at any time ?

All apps listed in Overview UI are background, right? will they be released by system control at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks listed in the overview may be released when the system needs resources. To get a better idea about retention of processes, take a look at this link around "cached process" https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks! Will the current app be placed into background if I press Home key ?

Comment: yes, but it can also be destroyed. You just don't know and need to respect the proper lifecycle callbacks of your activites